# how to update entity data source version in toolbox?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to update entity data source version in toolbox ,I've entity datasource version 6 installed as shown in screen shot#2 but the version in toolbox is still old(4.5.2) as showin in screen shot#1,how can I get it to use the latest?

[image]

**Entity data source6 installed:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

right click on Data> choose items> Browse> Locate your dll that would be in your package folder of project directory and press OK. Your component would be added in Toolbox.

Comment: I think I installed  a wrong dll...where can I get the latest dll for `system.web.entity.dll` , specificlaly I am looking for https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: That is inside GAC (MSIL folder) which VS version you are using?

Comment: Rajput - am using VS 2015,my question is how can I get the latets version(6 and higher ) of this dll?